# Can IKImageBrowserView display multi-line titles?

Tags: cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

I'd like my `IKImageBrowserView` to display long titles by wrapping them and displaying them in multiple lines, but I've been unable to achieve this.

I've tried changing the size of the titleFrame returned in the `ImageBrowserCell` subclass and also setting the paragraph style on the title so that it should wrap (`NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`) but I only ever get a single line of text.

Has anyone tried this? Any other suggestion I might try?

Answer (score 5):

Not easily, I'm afraid. One way you can do it is by leaving `imageTitle` blank and drawing text on a `CALayer`. I was able to make it work with fairly decent results:

[image]

First things first -- since you're not going to be using the standard `imageTitle` property, you want to create a new title property in your `<IKImageBrowserItem>`-conforming data object. I called mine simply `title`.

Then, you want to create an `IKImageBrowserCell` subclass. Make sure to tell your `IKImageBrowserView` you're using a custom cell; I just wrote a quick category for this:

```
@implementation IKImageBrowserView(CustomCell)
- (IKImageBrowserCell *)newCellForRepresentedItem:(id)cell
{
    return [[MyCustomImageBrowserCell alloc] init];
}
@end
```

Next, in your custom cell, override the method `- (CALayer *)layerForType:(NSString *)type`. Create and return a CALayer for a specific layer location type:

```
- (CALayer *)layerForType:(NSString *)type
{    
    if( [type isEqualToString:IKImageBrowserCellBackgroundLayer] )
    {       
        CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
        layer.delegate = self;
        layer.frame = self.frame; // the cell's frame
        layer.name = type; // a way to refer to the layer location type during drawing if need be
        [layer setNeedsDisplay];
        return layer;
    }

    return [super layerForType:type];
}
```

Then, implement the `-drawLayer:inContext:` method in your custom cell to handle the layer's drawing:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Set the current context.
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    NSGraphicsContext *nscg = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:context flipped:NO];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nscg];

    NSString *title = [self.representedItem title];

    // Wrap and center the text
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
    [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];

    NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [attrs setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
    [attrs setObject:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    CGFloat padding = 4.0f;

    [title drawInRect:NSMakeRect(
        0, 
        -(self.imageFrame.size.height + padding), 
        self.frame.size.width, 
        100
    ) withAttributes:attrs];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach does have a few drawbacks. The text doesn't get a blue selection background like `imageTitle` does. You can, however, draw your own selection background using an `NSBezierPath` inside a custom CALayer for the `IKImageBrowserCellSelectionLayer`.

Hope this is enough to go on.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually ended up using a CATextLayer to do essentially what you suggested. (We had already customized IKImageBrowserCellSelectionLayer to draw a border around the entire frame to indicate selection, so there were no issues there.)

Comment: Thanks. I had to add -(NSRect)imageContainerFrame;
 and play with the numbers a bit, but this works. No antialiasing, though.

Comment: This is a pretty great little tutorial for custom drawing cells in an IKImageBrowserView, thanks!