# Finder like IKImageBrowserCell

Tags: cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

I am trying to customize an IKImageBrowserCell to have something close to the Finder.

For the moment my issue is to have a title in 2 lines. Do you have any experience of what need to be modified in order to achieve this?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by drawing your title on a `CALayer` returned from the `- (CALayer *)layerForType:(NSString *)type` method of a subclassed `IKImageBrowserCell`.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880916/can-ikimagebrowserview-display-multi-line-titles/7218700#7218700).